# What is the fastest way to react to UDP datagrams in Python?

Tags: sockets, callback, udp, twisted, latency

I am writing a specific application which must render an image on-screen based on data coming over UDP protocol, with a minimal latency possible. Overall program design doesn't matter, code cleanliness or maintainability doesn't matter, either. I need latencies of 1 ms (for processing the datagram and calling a callback which flips the videobuffer) or below that.
Right now, I am considering the following approaches: `socket.socket().recvfrom()`, `selectors.DefaultSelector().register()`, `asyncore.dispatcher`, `multiprocessing.Process`, `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor().submit()`, `twisted.internet.protocol.ConnectedDatagramProtocol`
While `socket.recvfrom()` is the simplest approach, it implies a `while true` loop underneath, I believe, is blocking and doesn't allow *listening* for datagrams if they were sent before the `recvfrom()` method was called (i.e. doesn't have a buffer), and my application is gonna receive datagrams at a 1500 Hz frequency.
Is `twisted` framework fast enough? Is it `select`-based or callback-based?
My personal preference is that I use ProcessPoolExecutor, although I think having to call a callback wastes some fractions of a millisecond, while procedural single-threaded code is the fastest.
I also want to avoid function call overhead, therefore cannot afford calling some sort of a callback for every datagram I receive.
Which should I choose?

Comment: How fast do you think you can refresh the display?  60 times a second?  120 times a second?  How fast do you think a person looking at the display can see it update?  What benefit is responding to the network faster than you can actually update the display?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone, i only need to update it once, when a particularly important data arrives - but when it does, i need to do it fast; there will be a 240 hz display, potentially with a G-sync

Answer (score 1):

This question is not really answerable as asked.

1. Most likely, handling UDP datagrams is not going to be the limiting factor in this application. At the very least, you're probably going to need to authenticate or at least error-check this data, which means you'll need to do some cryptography.
2. You'll need to implement something and measure in the environments you care about. An answer that might be correct for one version of linux for one profile of data might be completely wrong on a slightly different platform with slightly different input data characteristics.  All of the approaches you mentioned are probably fine performance-wise, so I'd focus on something that allows you to organize your code in a reasonable way and then only switch strategies if it doesn't meet your performance budget.

To answer your more specific question here, Twisted itself is based around multiplexors (we try to avoid `select` which has performance and scalability issues, but yes, `select` is one mechanism it can use).

Comment: data validity is not an issue here, and no cryptography is required - the data feed is coming over a local network, separated from all public networks by 'thin air'